# Is there a math formula for converting string into integer on my own?

Tags: python, string, integer, numbers, project

EDIT: sorry if this is confusing but simply i want to make my own int() function for a school project

I am creating this code for a project at my school, the current formula I have for adding an integer to the end of a number is: "curnumber = curnumber + (integer - curnumber)", kind of like if you want x to be 13 and the current number is 2, you'd do something like **"x = x + (13 - 2)"** and it'd return the number but I don't know how to combine the numbers, it's really confusing, I'm able to get the number from a single character using this code: 
`def singleint(num):`

```
    int_ = 0
    if num == '0':
        int_ = 0
    elif num == '1':
        int_ = 1
    elif num == '2':
        int_ = 2
    elif num == '3':
        int_ = 3
    elif num == '4':
        int_ = 4
    elif num == '5':
        int_ = 5
    elif num == '6':
        int_ = 6
    elif num == '7':
        int_ = 7
    elif num == '8':
        int_ = 8
    elif num == '9':
        int_ = 9
    return int_`
```

and my total current code is:

```
def singleint(num):
    int_ = 0
    if num == '0':
        int_ = 0
    elif num == '1':
        int_ = 1
    elif num == '2':
        int_ = 2
    elif num == '3':
        int_ = 3
    elif num == '4':
        int_ = 4
    elif num == '5':
        int_ = 5
    elif num == '6':
        int_ = 6
    elif num == '7':
        int_ = 7
    elif num == '8':
        int_ = 8
    elif num == '9':
        int_ = 9
    return int_

def tonumber(str_):
    num = 0
    x = 0
    for char in list(str(str_)):
        c = singleint(char)
        print(type(c))
        new = (c - num)
        num = num + new
        x += 1
    return num

print(str(tonumber(192)))
```

I really need help with this, thanks

Comment: To come up with a formula to append a digit to the right of an integer think about first shifting all the digits of the integer one place to the left (you can do that multiplying by the base 10) and then add the last digit. Another tip: if you are allowed to use the ord() function there is another neat (and much shorter) way to implement your singleint() function.

Comment: thanks paul, my brain was destroying when trying to think of it

Comment: looking back on this i can say this looks so much like yanderedev's code lmao

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to see if all the characters in a string is numeric by using isnumeric() method, and if true, then use int() to convert it.

```
def convert_number(string_format):
    if string_format.isnumeric():
         return int(string_format)
    else:
         return None
```

Comment: no, that's not it, i have to manually convert it without the int() function

Comment: I hope this would help: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/convert-string-to-integer-without-using-any-in-built-functions/

Answer (score 3):

I'm not 100% sure what you're asking here but I think the answer to your question is:

```
int(num)
```

That'll convert the string to an integer.

Comment: OP wants to do it without the `int` function.